# Set a specific color to progress bar in bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I want to set a specific color to the progress bar in bootstrap other than the predefined success, info, warning and danger

i added the following code in bootstrap-theme.css:

```
.progress-bar-passing {
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7fff7f 0%, #449d44 100%);
 background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #7fff7f 0%, #449d44 100%);
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#7fff7f), to(#449d44));
 background-image:         linear-gradient(to bottom, #7fff7f 0%, #449d44 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff7fff7f', endColorstr='#ff449d44', GradientType=0);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

and used this in html:

```
<div class="progress">
                          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-passing" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:10%">
                            40% Complete (success)
                          </div>
</div>
```

but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: Overwrite the css with urs :)

Comment: referred this site to get the values to be set:
http://bootstrapdesigntools.com/tools/bootstrap-progress-bar-designer/

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find different color progress bars

Add `progress-striped` class to get strip look.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Progress Bar</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .bs-example{
     margin: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head> 
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
 <div class="progress progress-striped">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 60%;">
   <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
  </div>
 </div>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" style="width: 60%;">
   <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
  </div>
 </div>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 60%;">
   <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to add my own color and category and not use the predefined ones